# Multi-class Keras perceptron classifier is classifying everything as a single class

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

My dataset has the following shape

```
[[  1.   337.   118.   ...   9.65   1.     0.92]
 [  2.   324.   107.   ...   8.87   1.     0.76]
 [  3.   316.   104.   ...   8.     1.     0.72]
 ...
 [498.   330.   120.   ...   9.56   1.     0.93]
 [499.   312.   103.   ...   8.43   0.     0.73]
 [500.   327.   113.   ...   9.04   0.     0.84]]
```

That last column is the dependent variable, all others are independent variables. The first column is the ID variable, which I'm getting rid of because I'm assuming it provides no information.

I'm grouping the dependent variable in 5 bins symbolizing 5 classes this way:

```
X = raw[:,1:8]
Y = raw[:,8]

def mapping(x):
  if (x <= 0.5):
    return 0;
  if (x <= 0.65):
    return 1;
  if (x <= 0.8):
    return 2;
  if (x <= 0.9):
    return 3;
  if (x <= 1):
    return 4;

Y = np.array(list(map(mapping, Y)))
```

The resulting class frequency looks like this:

```
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([ 39, 119, 200,  81,  61]))
```

So it's not like there's a prevalence of one class over the others.

However, when running my multi-layered perceptron model, it keeps classifying everything in one class. Which class depends on the run, but it's the same for every record.

My model is the following:

```
Y = to_categorical(Y)

train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=10)

learning_rate = 0.001
n_layer_1 = 64
n_layer_2 = 64
num_classes = 5

def build_classification_model(train_set):
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(n_layer_1, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=tuple([train_set.shape[1]])),
    layers.Dense(n_layer_2, activation=tf.nn.relu, ),
    layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
  ])

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()

  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['categorical_accuracy', 'mean_squared_error'])
  return model

model = build_classification_model(train_X)
num_epochs = 200

print('Training...')
history = model.fit(train_X, train_Y, batch_size=500, epochs=num_epochs, verbose=0)
print('Done.')
prediction = model.predict(train_X)
```

With `prediction` looking like this every run:

```
array([[2.17507738e-17, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        2.74140113e-14],
       [1.16876501e-17, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        1.38829174e-14],
       [2.22264258e-18, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        4.08135584e-15],
       ...,
       [2.78243342e-17, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        2.62153224e-14],
       [1.69924047e-16, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        1.70491795e-13],
       [5.26733592e-17, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        4.98645043e-14]], dtype=float32)
```

Notice it picked everything as class 3.

It doesn't matter if I add a new layer, change the number of nodes in the hidden layers or change the learning rate: probabilities for every record look very much the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I would suggest first:

1. Splitting your data in a stratified manner during the `train_test_split` to ensure your train and test sets contain a representative number of samples of all classes. This is easily implemented:

`train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, 
     random_state=10, stratify=Y)`

This will ensure the model is trained on a fair amount of samples from all classes.

2. Your batch size is too high, I'm assuming there is a misunderstanding here. When using SGD, the batch size is the number of samples processed by the network before a gradient update is made, not the number of training examples you have. From the look of it you don't even have 500 training examples. A small batch size, default values of 32 are often used, ensures multiple updates of the gradient per epoch. A large amount of gradient updates are much more effective for gradient descent, which takes small steps at each gradient update. 200 updates, as your network is currently set, is not a lot considering your amount of parameters, so decrease the batch size!

Comment: Also, keep in mind that looking at predictions on your training set is not an indication of the models generalisation error. But in your case when one class is predicted even on the training set, I doubt the model is able to generalise.